# Specializing method template while checking for subtype

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae, template-specialization

What is the syntax to specialize a template for a method whilst also checking that some subtype exists?

```
// Syntax works fine for functions
template<class T, class... Assertions> void my_function();

template <class list_t, class list_t::value_type>
void my_function() { }

// Doesn't work for methods
class MyClass {
    template<class T, class... Assertions> void my_method();
};

// Commenting out the next two lines results in successful compile
template <class list_t, class list_t::value_type>
void MyClass::my_method() { }

int main() { }
```

Clang gives me:

```
out-of-line definition of 'my_method' does not match any declaration in 'MyClass'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specializing neither the template method nor the function here. You are just overloading free template function and trying to overload the method in a strange way. To make it work You should use tag dispatch (as partial function template specialization is impossible in C++) or `constexpr if` if Your compiler supports C++17

Comment: How do I check if a subtype exists?

Answer (score 0):

Specialisation syntax is as follows:

```
// dummy list_t...
struct list_t
{
   using value_type = int;
};

// standard implementation:
template<class T, class... Assertions>
void my_function() { }

// specialization
template <>
void my_function<list_t, list_t::value_type>() { }

class MyClass
{
    template<class T, class... Assertions>
    void my_method();
};

// standard implementation:
template<class T, class... Assertions>
void MyClass::my_method() { }

// specialisation
template <>
void MyClass::my_method<list_t, list_t::value_type>() { }
```

Comment: list_t is supposed to be a generic type that has a `::value_type`; not a concrete type.

Comment: Something like this: `template <class list_t, class VT = typename list_t::value_type> void my_function() { }`

Comment: `out-of-line definition of 'my_method' does not match any declaration in 'MyClass'`

Comment: Be aware that you cannot partially specialise functions in C++! With above, you would have produced an ambiguous overload, though.

Comment: Is <list_t> a template itself?

Comment: In my code, it is a template parameter; it does not name a specific type.

Comment: Looks to me as if you wanted something like `template <typename t_list> void my_function<t_list, typename t_list::value_type>();`. Unfortunately, this is a partial function specialisation, which is not (yet?) supported by the language.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't clear to me what do you exactly want.

If you want that `my_method()` is implemented only when `T` is a class/struct whit a type `value_type` in it, and you want a compilation error when called with a `T` without a `value_type` in it, I suggest the use of SFINAE through `declval()` and `decltype()`.

Something as

```
template <typename T>
auto my_method ()
   -> decltype( std::declval<typename T::value_type>(), void() )
 { }
```

If you can use C++17, instead of `decltype( std::declval<typename T::value_type>(), void() )`, you can use `std::void_t<T::value_type>`.

If you want a `my_method()` with with a more generic version and a specialized version for classes/structs with a `value_type` in it, I suggest to develop a generic `my_method()` that simply call another method `my_method_helper()` adding an `int` value

```
template <typename T>
void my_method ()
 { my_method_helper<T>(0); }
```

and combining SFINAE and function overloading for `my_method_helper()` with a `my_method_helper()` that receive a `long` (so not exactly a `int`) and is ever enabled for the more generic version

```
template <typename T>
void my_method_helper (long)
 { }
```

and a version that receive exactly a `int` (so preferred, when available, over the `long` version) but is enabled only when `T` contain a `value_type`.

```
template <typename T>
auto my_method_helper (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<typename T::value_type>(), void() )
 { }
```

So the `my_method_helper(int)` is called when `T` contain a `value_type` and the `my_method_helper(long)` is called otherwise.

The following is a full compiling example (with method names changed)

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
 {
   template <typename T>
   auto method_1 ()
      -> decltype( std::declval<typename T::value_type>(), void() )
    { std::cout << "method_1 " << std::endl; }

   template <typename T>
   auto method_2 (int)
      -> decltype( std::declval<typename T::value_type>(), void() )
    { std::cout << "method_2 specialized" << std::endl; }

   template <typename T>
   void method_2 (long)
    { std::cout << "method_2 generic" << std::endl; }

   template <typename T>
   void method_2 ()
    { method_2<T>(0); }
 };

struct foo
 { using value_type = int; };

int main()
 {
   MyClass mc;

   mc.method_1<foo>();
   // mc.method_1<int>(); // compilation error

   mc.method_2<foo>(); // call specialized version
   mc.method_2<int>(); // call generic version
 }
```

Partially Off Topic: I don't understand what do you mean with "Syntax works fine for functions" with

```
template<class T, class... Assertions> void my_function();

template <class list_t, class list_t::value_type>
void my_function() { }
```

How do you call `my_function()` ?